# RSYNC requiring an ssh directory or file to succeed

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I've had a hunt around for an answer to this but I don't know if it's an obscure thing or I am not reading answers correctly.
When I try to rsync between two machines using SSH I am getting this error unless there is a directory called ssh in the list:-

```
 rsync: link_stat "/rsync/ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

The rsync itself works, transferring the files and folders as I would expect, but I don't know why it needs the ssh folder in the list. The command I am running is:-

```
rsync -avzh ssh /rsync/ root@192.168.56.103:/rsync/
```

and I am running as root. This is between two VMs on a host only network running oracle linux 6.9

Many thanks to anyone who can point out where I am going wrong. I did think it was something to do with where I put the ssh in the command line but moving it does not appear to solve the problem.

David

Comment: You'll need the -e flag to use that `ssh` bit: `rsync -avzh -e ssh /rsync/....` This should get you past that error where it will either work, or give you a fresh issue to work through.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: JNevill - looks like the -e flag is the one. jww - Thanks for the feedback. I'll try stack exchange next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to specify the remote shell command without using the -e switch. It is likely that you can simply remove the ssh argument. According the `man rsync`:

> For remote transfers, a modern rsync uses ssh for its communications,
>   but it may have  been  configured to use a different remote shell by
>   default, such as rsh or remsh

So, do

> rsync -avzh /rsync/ root@192.168.56.103:/rsync/

If your system really doesn't default to using ssh, add -e before your ssh argument.

> rsync -avzh -e ssh /rsync/ root@192.168.56.103:/rsync/

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like I need the -e option in there.

Answer (score -2):

It's trying to sync a file called "ssh" and the directory "/rsync/" to 192.168.56.103:/rsync/, however the sender doesn't have a file called "ssh", which is what the message is complaining about.

It's not a great message, but few are. 8-)